# How to run a command on last edit in vim (i.e. indent)

Tags: vim

I added some lines in insert mode and now I would like to run some command only on these edit. How to perform it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Marks `'[` and `']` locate the start and end lines of newest inserted or changed text. From this, you can simply run

```
 :'[,']>
```

to indent those lines once. See `:help '[` for more examples. And for instance, formatting the code will happen with

```
'[=']
```

and formating a chunk of text with

```
'[gq']
```